# Can Observer break the Event in Magento?

Tags: php, magento

I am new to Magento. I want to build an observer which on cancellation of an order will perform a query to my database and will decide whether the order is cancellable or not (This is decided on the basis of a certain state.). If it can't be cancelled, then it should break the cancel event and display a message that the order cannot be cancelled.

Which event I should choose, `order_cancel_after` or `sales_order_item_cancel`, and how can I break out of this event in between?

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Do you mean you wish to stop any other observers from handling the event after you?

Comment: No. I want that when observer detect any event, before that event execute, observer check certain conditions and can stop the event from executing. (For Example - Use of 'break' in for loop or while loop.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no general answer to this, it depends on the context where the event is triggered and what happens there afterwards.

The events don't have an interface to "stop" them and they are not tied to the actual "event" (i.e. order cancellation) other than by name.

So you will have to look at the code of `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item` where `sales_order_item_cancel` gets triggered (`order_cancel_after` is obviously the wrong place to look because at that point the order is already cancelled):

```
/**
 * Cancel order item
 *
 * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item
 */
public function cancel()
{
    if ($this->getStatusId() !== self::STATUS_CANCELED) {
        Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_order_item_cancel', array('item'=>$this));
        $this->setQtyCanceled($this->getQtyToCancel());
        $this->setTaxCanceled($this->getTaxCanceled() + $this->getBaseTaxAmount() * $this->getQtyCanceled() / $this->getQtyOrdered());
        $this->setHiddenTaxCanceled($this->getHiddenTaxCanceled() + $this->getHiddenTaxAmount() * $this->getQtyCanceled() / $this->getQtyOrdered());
    }
    return $this;
}
```

You see that there is no additional check after the event was dispatched, but it would be possible to set the `qty_to_cancel` attributes to `0` to uneffect the cancelling.

Your observer method:

```
public function salesOrderItemCancel(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $item = $observer->getEvent()->getItem();
    if (!$this->_isCancellable($item->getOrder())) {
        $item->setQtyToCancel(0);
        $this->_showErrorMessage();
    }
}
```

Note that you don't have to set `tax_canceled` or `hidden_tax_canceled` because they depend on `qty_canceled` and thus will stay 0.

Comment: I totally Agree with You. But by doing hit and trial, I came with this solution that if while in observer method is in progress and I redirect it some other page, I can stop that event in between.

Comment: Redirecting basically exits the current script. So yes, this works too but it is kind of a brute force method that will not always be intended.

Comment: Yes. But after too much searching for it, I finally went up doing that and it is would do my job. :)
Thank you too :)